# Auto Refresh view in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application that depends on a database. The user can post something, but once they post it they must exit out of the current view and go back into it to see the post. How can I change it so that once the user makes the post, they see it. Its essentailly an auto refresh. This is the code that originally populates the tableview.

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{
   NSError *error;
   json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

}

-(void) start{
   NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kRecieveUrl]; 
   [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", @"id", _post_id]];
   [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:postString];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   [self getData:data];    
   NSLog(@"Json:%@", postString);
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   TableViewCell *cell = [self->tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"]; 
   NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.content.text = [info objectForKey:@"response_text"];
   return cell;
}
```

When the user sends a new post, that would populate this tableview, they have to exit out and go back in for that new post to be there. I want it to show them the new post once they send it.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information - UI objects contain state that usually doesn't automatically update. They say what you tell them to.

Comment: Well once the user presses send to post their post, the view should refresh. The view should reload

Comment: How do you put information into that view in the first place?

Comment: I have a method that calls the information from the database

Comment: So to refresh the view you should probably call the same thing again.

Comment: I have tried that, but it does not work

Comment: No one can provide specific help with so little info. Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Please take some time to format it properly. Indent it properly and remove all of the unneeded blank lines. Put some effort into asking a good question. If you can't bother with a little effort, why should people bother putting effort in to help? Good questions get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an NSTimer to refresh your data :

add this timer in your view did load for example

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; //60 sec timer
```

and add this method

```
-(void) reloadTable
{
   [self start];
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```